# How to attach collapsible of font-awesome icon to parent li of nested list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slide toggle nested list `<li>` structure as below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(e.target);

    if (element.is('li') == true && element.children('ol').children('li').length >= 1) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(e.target).children('ol').slideToggle(function() {});
    }
  })
})
```

```css
ol.example li {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #0088cc;
  background: #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ol.example ol {
  display: none;
}

ol.example li a:before {
  content: "\f054";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol class="example">
  <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account Statement</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account Closure</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Internal Account</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">User</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">User Management</a>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Reset User Password</a></li>
          <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Role and Right</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">List Logged-in User</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">User</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">LogOut</a></li>
</ol>
```

So, I tried to apply CSS or Javascript to attach an icon of font-awesome collapsible and expansible to parent list `<li>` as it is clicked to slide toggle, but so far without any luck.

Is there any CSS or Javascript way I can achieve this effect?

Comment: Just add the font-family of FontAwesome properly to ol.example li a:before selector. I will post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS content to achieve that. Add classes toggle-tab-plus and toggle-tab-minus with a pseudo selector(inside a span because you want them to be in the same line). And switch them when you toggle. You can use small images too in the content if you want them to look like something specific.I used this technique to do left navigation on this site. I used an 'x' instead of '-' to collapse and '+' to expand.
https://www.simplystamps.com/address-stamps/view-all
Below is the js fiddle for above example.

jsfiddle.net/yash009/5khotxu0/2 [Working js fiddle for the example above](http://jsfiddle.net/yash009/5khotxu0/2)

```
<div>your Div<span class="toggle-tab-plus"></span></div>

/*css*/
    .toggle-tab-plus:before {
        content: "+";
    }
    .toggle-tab-minus:before {
        content: "-";
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, what I want to achieve is to add collapsible icon (+) or (-) state to my parent list item as they are collapsed or expand :) . the collapsed and expand blocks are currently fine :)

Comment: I have edited my answer please take a look I think the solution should be along these lines.

Comment: Thanks, I could not access the site, access denied. Could you provide a full runnable snippet of this, html, css, and javascript :)

Comment: it is close to my answer above, how could I include your class `.toggle-tab-plus` and `.toggle-tab-minus` working for above snippet? Thank very much.

Comment: Here is a working jsfiddle link.   https://jsfiddle.net/yash009/5khotxu0/2/. Please upvote the answer if it works for you. Remember you can use images in the content too instead of boring plus and minus text :)

Comment: Thanks for you effort helping on this :)

Answer (score 0):

@Yashchaturvedi Yes it is, I could manage this end-result by jquery `.toggleClass()` as below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    var element = $(e.target);

    if (element.is('li') == true && element.children('ol').children('li').length >= 1) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $(e.target).children('ol').slideToggle(function() {
        $(e.target).closest('li').find('a:first').toggleClass('red');
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
ol.example li {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #0088cc;
  background: #eeeeee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ol.example ol {
  display: none;
}

ol.example li a:before {
  content: "\f054";
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol class="example">
  <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account Statement</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Account Closure</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Internal Account</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">User</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">User Management</a>
        <ol>
          <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Reset User Password</a></li>
          <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">Role and Right</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">List Logged-in User</a></li>
      <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">User</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)" style="visibility: visible;">LogOut</a></li>
</ol>
```

Just close to what I wish to be, yet I still unable to attach icon to each state of toggle, just now I used class `red` an example. Appreciate for any suggestion, Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your original question. Do not post questions in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the font-family properly to display the icons. Just one change is all it takes in your code to display the icon.

```
ol.example li a:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f054";
}
```

To make it easier, directly use the classes provided by font-awesome. Find required info on their docs: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

To toggle the icons, just add a parent class to differentiate collapsed and expanded states and use different icons for both.